# What is the exact compression that is happening from the first sequence of raw audio waveform data to the second sequence?

Tags: audio, compression

The first sequence of audio samples is recorded in JavaScript from the browser in mono, PCM format, 32-bit, and 96,000 Hz.
I wrote this audio file as a blob to a server through a JavaScript FormData object using ajax.
When I retrieved the audio from the server, I received the second sequence of audio samples. It has been downsampled to 48000 Hz and altered somehow.

Raw audio samples: 
[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a compression at all (if it was, there wouldn't be a 0 every even position). Also, WAV is just a container format, we can't tell you what's inside. Only you know how you encoded the contents of the wav file. And honestly, even if this was a compression, how are we supposed to know what it does based on less than 100 samples?!

Comment: There shouldn't be a 0 every even position- it should be blank (spreadsheet error). The second file is at 48000 Hz, so it seems every even sample is tossed out?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: i don't grok this question, really.  do you get it, @MarcusMüller ?

Comment: I edited the question again. Does it still not make sense?

Comment: @user46041 no, because there's no compression happening here, as far as robert or I could tell, see my first comment. Again, you have the audio file AND the audio encoder, so why don't you just look up what that encoder does?